# What is the format of 3D Face input?

Tags: 3d, computer-vision, face-recognition

My team has chosen topic: **3D Face Recognition** for a final project in class, I know this is a very hard topic, but I really want to do this.

But after a ton of time research, I've faced with some problem:

- I don't know the format of 3D Face data, does it is the same with 2D data?
- How can we find keypoint from 3D Face data?
- Finally, can you suggest some paper write about 3D Face Recognition?

Thanks for your help

Comment: foer example you can always map a 3d model to 2d space and use 2d face recognition instead

Comment: here are papers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-dimensional_face_recognition

Comment: I am confused about 3d format, could you explain it?

Comment: I have to read the literature myself. Havent worked with 3D object recognition. But you try and if you need more help try asking a specific question

Comment: As I know, 2D Face mode,  input is the image (ex: 255x255x3), but for 3D Face model, input needs to get from 3D scanner. I haven't work with 3d scanner. So, I don't know what it returns

Comment: You can assume a 3d model of x,y,z coordinates. Even if a 3d scanner does not return such a format, it is starightforward to transform to one. The format is mostly irrelevant as any format is almost trivially transformed to another equivalent

Comment: oke thank you very much, I just found some representation of 3D data: point cloud, 3D mesh, depth image (2.5D image or range image). But I don't understand the 2.5D, can you explain it.

Comment: if i am not mistaken it is 3d data represented in condensed form via a 2d image. So it is not pure 3d thats why it is refered as 2.5D, but it is easy to look it up